# Select From List By Value doesnt find Locator

Tags: python, robotframework

I'm trying select an value by the list, but i got an error, can someone help me please?
i've  tried many types of xpath but nothing works..

`Select From List By Value    ${erpPO.comboProgramado}    ${12}`

I need select **TELETRABALHO** by the list, using Python and RobotFramework..
I'm using the keyword: Select From List By Value
But i got this error: Element with locator
**'//select[@class='form-control form-control-sm col-lg-12 ng-dirty ng-valid ng-touched']' not found.**

[Screenshot by the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HByV4.png)
[Screenshot by the locator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vckk6.png)

Thanks !

Comment: Read [tour] and [mcve] and edit your post accordingly

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.